# "As an IT guy, please use both backups and version control.." Which guy is meant here?

Tags: usage

> As an IT guy, please use both backups and version control for all important files, especially anything for clients or your business. Please, please, please.

Is the speaker announces himself as an IT guy or calls the addressee an IT guy?

Note: the original text is a comment under [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/977086/how-to-make-a-folder-un-deletable-by-myself-inadvertently) if it helps.

Comment: He's referring to himself, as mkennedy says, but I think it would have been easier to parse this sentence had he said "As an IT guy I have to ask: please use..."

Answer (score 3):

The statement, "As a(n) XX person," is short for "Speaking as a(n) XX person." That is, the person making the statement has expertise in a particular field or area and you should take their advice.